# Need To Organize this array in such formate to store in mysql, and it can have many sec node as in associative array, Please let me know

Tags: logic

[sec] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => "sfdsdf"
                                        )

```
                                [title] => "test"
                                [p] => "".
                                [sec] = array(
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => "sfdsdf"
                                    )

                                [title] => "test"
                                [p] => "".
                                    )

                                          )
                            )
                     )
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer, we can organize this values with recursive call, we just have to check whenever sec index comes, just call it self.